# aws cli is installed differently on my Mac

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

when I do this

```
"/users/akshay/bin/aws --version"
```

I get

```
"aws-cli/1.15.57 Python/2.7.10 Darwin/17.6.0 botocore/1.10.56"
```

why should I always use the path

```
"/users/akshay/bin/aws"
```

to refer to the aws cli? And why can't I just do

```
aws --version?
```

Comment: Because it's not on your path? Differently than what?

Comment: my question is why can't I just use "aws --version" and not "/users/akshay/bin/aws --version"

Comment: [What is PATH on Mac OS](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111550/what-is-path-on-a-mac-os)

Comment: Because it's not on your path?